# php scandir --> search for files/directories

Tags: php

I searched before I ask, without lucky..

I looking for a simple script for myself, which I can search for files/folders. Found this code snippet in the php manual (I think I need this), but it is not work for me.

"Was looking for a simple way to search for a file/directory using a mask. Here is such a function.

By default, this function will keep in memory the scandir() result, to avoid scaning multiple time for the same directory."

```
<?php 
function sdir( $path='.', $mask='*', $nocache=0 ){ 
    static $dir = array(); // cache result in memory 
    if ( !isset($dir[$path]) || $nocache) { 
        $dir[$path] = scandir($path); 
    } 
    foreach ($dir[$path] as $i=>$entry) { 
        if ($entry!='.' && $entry!='..' && fnmatch($mask, $entry) ) { 
            $sdir[] = $entry; 
        } 
    } 
    return ($sdir); 
} 
?>
```

Thank you for any help,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = new RegexIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('DIRECTORY HERE')
    ),
    '/REGEX HERE/',
    RegexIterator::MATCH
);

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "$v\n"; //$v will be the filename
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answers, Artefacto-s solution is good for me, but! Is there similar solution without regex? Or what is the regex, when I only want to search in the filenames with/without masks?

example: stackoverflow.zip and I want to search on "overflow", or "stack", or "stackoverflow"...

Thank you very much!

Comment: For that you only need the regexes `overflow`, `stack` and `stackoverflow`. Those three would match "stackoverflow.zip". You can use regexes in that simple way, you just have to be careful to escape characters that have special meaning.

Comment: Soo simple!! Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 nice and efficient way to do it. Little off the topic to this question but could you share your ideas to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356376/php-creating-extensible-cms-system

Answer (score 1):

try using `glob()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

i you just want to search for a file, you can use this snippet:

```
    <?php   
    $s = $get['s'];
    $e = ".htm";
    $folders = array("data1", "data2", "data3");
    $files = array(); // nothing needed here. anything in this array will be showed as a search result.
    for($i=0;$i<=count($folders)-1;$i++) {
        $glob = glob($folders[$i]);
        $files = array_merge($files, $glob[$i]);
    }
    echo "Search - $s<br><br>";
    if(count($files) == 1) {
        echo "<li><a href='$files[0]'>".heir($files[0])."</a></li>";
    }
    if(count($files) != 1) {
        for($i=0;$i<=count($files)-1;$i++) {
            echo "<li><a href='$files[$i]'>".heir($files[$i])."</a></li>";  
        }
    }
    if(count($files) == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, no hits.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is really nice, but it made me think of the Spl iterators on the rocks. Fabien Potencier explains how he created the Finder classes in symfony here:

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/43/find-your-files

I also use his finder classes, they have a very nice chained interface.

- 5.3+ standalone version (From sf2): https://github.com/symfony/Finder

**Example:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in(__DIR__);

foreach ($finder as $file) {
   print $file->getRealpath()."\n";
}
```

**and also..**

```
$finder->files()->name('*.php');
// or 
$finder->files()->size('>= 1K')->size('<= 2K');
$finder->date('since yesterday');
```

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/finder.html

**The PHP5.2+ version from the sf1.4 framework:** 
http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/lib/util/sfFinder.class.php

This version is slightly different, and less fancy, but also does the job. You'll need to create an sfException class though, it's its only tie-in with the symfony framework. You may create your own sfException Class:

```
class sfException extends Exception { }
```

Documentation can be found here: http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/finder