# problem in showing all files of a directory

Tags: php, directory

hey guys  im looking for a way to show all mp3 files in a directory

this is my code  to get that :

```
    if ($handle = opendir($dirPath)) {

       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

         if ($file = ".mp3" && $file = "..") {
             echo '
             <track>
              <location>'.$dirPath.$file.'</location>
              <creator>'.$file.'</creator>
            </track>
            ';    

          }
       }
   closedir($handle);
}
```

now i know that this script will only show mp3 files in parent directory  , but i need to show all mp3 files in all directory inside parent directory

problem is this code cant show files inside sub directories !

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861834

Comment: *(reference)* [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: oops , that was close , sorry , i didnt find that before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code won't work at all. As you are setting the $file variable to ".." the result will be a lot of xml containing $dirPath and "..".

This is what you are looking for :)

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/files/');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{
    echo $file->getPathname() . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: good point , but 1st how to apply filter mp3 files . 2nd  the address $file->getPathname() this is not a web address but its like system path :   britney\mylove\heart.mp3  and it would be useless path for web application !

Comment: @MacTaylor [Introduction to SPL](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html) should have everything you need to know for now

Comment: hey Gordon , the only problem cant fix , is getting web address . now the address is just like :britney\mylove\heart.mp3 and cant play the file . any point for that ?!

Comment: @MacTaylor see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156290/using-recursivedirectoryiterator-and-problem-in-path-name/3156351#3156351

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a recursive function to search for all the MP3s.

Also, you probably meant `if ($file == ".mp3" && $file == "..") {` instead of `if ($file = ".mp3" && $file = "..") {`, and after that's changed, you get a condition that's always false. What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 0):

like icktoofay said, you'll have to make a recursive function. also, your code has an error:

```
if ($file = ".mp3" && $file = "..") {
```

won't work (and `if ($file == ".mp3" && $file == "..") {` is wrong, too). that line should look like this:

```
if (substr($file,-4) == ".mp3" || $file == "..") {
```

if you want to show the ".." - else it's just like this:

```
if (substr($file,-4) == ".mp3") {
```

Comment: my main goal is to find all files in a directory , cause i know how to find files in parent directory and i did that . 

thanks for your point