# How to scan all the .m files using php?

Tags: php, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php scandir --> search for files/directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861834/php-scandir-search-for-files-directories)

I have a folder, inside this folder, have many subfolders, but I would like to scan all the subfolders, and scan all the .m file... How can I do so??

Here is the file:

```
/MyFilePath/
           /myPath.m
           /myPath2.m
           /myPath3.m
          /MyClasses/
                    /my.m
                    /my1.m
                    /my2.m
                    /my3.m
                    /Utilities/
                              /u1.m
                              /u2.m
                              /External/
                                       /a.m
                                       /b.m
                                       /c.m
                              /Internal/
                                       /d.m
                                       /e.m
                                       /f.m
                    /Views/
                           /a_v.m
                           /b_v.m
                           /c_v.m
                    /Controllers/
                                /a_vc.m
                                /b_vc.m
                                /c_vc.m
          /AnotherClasses/
                         /anmy.m
                         /anmy1.m
                         /anmy2.m
                         /anmy3.m
                    /Networking/
                               /net1.m
                               /net2.m
                               /net3.m
                              /External/
                              /Internal/
                    /Views/
                    /Controllers/
```

Comment: How do you mean "scan all the .m files"? Do you want to list the .m files or do you want to see what's INSIDE the files? Can the .m files be in any of the folders you have specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look to the PHP docs for details on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Here's an example that should do what you you want. It will return an array of all .m files in the sub directories. You can then loop through each file and read the contents if that is what you are interested in.

```
<?php
function get_m_files($root = '.'){ 
  $files  = array(); 
  $directories  = array(); 
  $last_letter  = $root[strlen($root)-1]; 
  $root  = ($last_letter == '\\' || $last_letter == '/') ? $root : $root.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $directories[]  = $root; 

  while (sizeof($directories)) { 
    $dir  = array_pop($directories); 
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) { 
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') { 
          continue; 
        } 
        $file  = $dir.$file; 
        if (is_dir($file)) { 
          $directory_path = $file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
          array_push($directories, $directory_path); 
        } elseif (is_file($file)) { 
          if (substr( $file, -strlen( ".m" ) ) == ".m") { 
              $files[]  = $file; 
          }               
        } 
      } 
      closedir($handle); 
    } 
  } 

  return $files; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Also, wouldn't this include files like `file.moo` and `so.m.txt`?

Answer (score 7):

You could also use some of the [SPL](http://php.net/spl)'s iterators.  A quick and basic example would look like:

```
$directories = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/search');
$flattened   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directories);
$filter      = new RegexIterator($flattened, '/\.in$/');

foreach ($filter as $file) {
    echo $file, PHP_EOL;
}
```

More infos (mostly incomplete):

- http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator
- http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator
- http://php.net/regexiterator

Comment: much better solution than all the others!

Answer (score 1):

```
function ScanForMFiles($dir){ 

    $return = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) { 
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 

            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
                if(is_dir($dir.$file)){
                    $return =  array_merge($return, ScanForMFiles($dir.$file."/")); 
                }
                else {
                    if(substr($file, -2) == '.m')
                        $return[] = $file;
                }
            } 
        } 

        closedir($handle); 
    }

    return $return;

}

var_dump(ScanForMFiles('./'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
function searchFiles($dir,$pattern,$recursive=false)
{
    $matches = array();

    $d = dir($dir);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
    {
        if (is_dir($d->path.$entry) && $recursive)
        {
            $subdir = $d->path.$entry;
            $matches = array_merge($matches,searchFiles($dir,$pattern,$recursive));
        }
        elseif (is_file($d->path.$entry) && preg_match($pattern,$entry))
        {
            $matches[] = $d->path.$entry;
        }
    }
    $d->close();
    return $matches;
}
```

Usage:

```
$matches = searchFiles("/mypath/","'[.]m$'i",true);
```